# OAuth2 Java - How to set Accept header

Tags: java, oauth

I'm trying to implement a "sign in with Github" feature for my site with a hybrid solution - the site's javascript does the initial login/credentials, and the redirect url is for a tomcat servlet continuing the access token request.

I'm using Google API oauth2 library for Java.

My code currently looks like this:

```
AuthorizationCodeTokenRequest tokenRequest =
    new AuthorizationCodeTokenRequest(
            new NetHttpTransport(),
            new JacksonFactory(),
            new GenericUrl("https://github.com/login/oauth/access_token"),
            code)
            .setClientAuthentication(
                new ClientParametersAuthentication(
                    GITHUB_CLIENT_ID, GITHUB_CLIENT_SECRET));

TokenResponse tokenResponse = tokenRequest.execute();
```

This doesn't work, and I'm getting the following exception:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unrecognized token 'access_token': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null')
```

I've looked into it, and found the response from Github is not in a json format (which the JacksonFactory expects), but actually looks like this:

```
access_token=xxxxxxxxxxx&scope=user%3Aemail&token_type=bearer
```

I've found in https://developer.github.com/v3/media/#request-specific-version that I need to set the Accept http header of the request to be *application/vnd.github.v3+json* for it to return something in json format.

How can I do this with Google's oauth2 api?

EDIT:
Based on [tinker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1452522/tinker)'s response, I solved with the following addition:

```
tokenRequest.setRequestInitializer(new HttpRequestInitializer()
{
    @Override
    public void initialize(HttpRequest request) throws IOException
    {
        request.getHeaders().setAccept("application/json");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create an HttpRequest and add the headers to that. Look at [javadoc](http://javadoc.google-http-java-client.googlecode.com/hg/1.8.3-beta/com/google/api/client/http/HttpRequest.html#setHeaders(com.google.api.client.http.HttpHeaders)) for setting the request headers here.

From the `AuthorizationCodeTokenRequest` you can get the `HttpRequestInitializer` using `getRequestInitializer()`. If this is null then you can create an initalizer and use `setRequestInitializer()` with the newly created object.

With the initializer you can now `initialize` the request that has the desired headers.

I haven't tested this so I'm not absolutely sure, but from the [docs](http://javadoc.google-oauth-java-client.googlecode.com/hg/1.8.0-beta/com/google/api/client/auth/oauth2/TokenRequest.html#getRequestInitializer()) this looks like the only way to do it.